# Is there a way to make an external hard drive appear as internal in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Title says it all, how can I make Windows XP treat my external hard-drive as an internal (system) hard drive?

I'm trying to install an application that will only accept an internal hard drive but I don’t have enough space on my only internal drive (`C:`).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  An application should not be able to tell the difference between an external storage location and an internal storage location

Comment: @Ramhound Well, it is, I have to select a drive before I input the folder name and it won't let me select a drive that is external (such as a USB pen drive). When I try to manually modify the path by changing the driver letter it displays a pop up window that demands the application be installed on a local drive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using NTFS on your C: drive do the following.

Create an empty folder on C drive. Then go to Control panel > administrative tools> computer management > Disk Management > right click the external drive and choose Change drive letter and paths > add > mount in the following NTFS folder

Comment: That kinda seems to work but I fail the free space check, do you know of a way to circumvent that?